# Get data from an .asp file

Tags: python

My girlfriend has been given the task of getting all the data from a webpage. The web page belongs to an adult education centre. To get to the webpage, you must first log in. The url is a .asp file.

She has to put the data in an Excel sheet. The entries are student names, numbers, ID card number, telephone, etc. There are thousands of entries. HR students alone has 70 pages of entries. This all shows up on the webpage as a table. It is possible to copy and paste.

I can handle Python openpyxl reasonably and I have heard of web-scraping, which I believe Python can do.

I don't know what .asp is.

Could you please give me some tips, pointers, about how to get the data with Python?

Can I automate this task?

Is this a case for MySQL? (About which I know nothing.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a really broad question and not really in the style of Stack Overflow. To give you some pointers anyway. In the end .asp files, as far as I know, behave like normal websites. Normal websites are interpreted in the browser like HTML, CSS etc. This can be parsed with Python. There are two approaches to this that I have used in the past that work. One is to use a library like `requests` to get the HTML of a page and then read it using the `BeautifulSoup` library. This gets more complex if you need to visit authenticated pages. The other option is to use `Selenium` for python. This module is more a tool to automate browsing itself. You can use this to automate visiting the website and entering login credentials and then read content on the page. There are probably more options which is why this question is too broad. Good luck with your project though!

EDIT: You do not need MySql for this. Especially not if the required output is an Excel file, which I would generate as a CSV instead because standard Python works better with CSV files than Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the tool called Octoparse.

Disclaimer: I've never used it myself, but only came close to using it. So, from my knowledge of its features, I think it would be useful for your need.